# How to prevent users from inputing numbers outside of the range i have given?

Tags: java, methods

Write a program that allows user to input two integers in the range of (between) 1 to 100, inclusive and print the product as an output. The program must call a method/function, named computeProduct, which takes in the two numbers and returns the product. The method/function should also check that the two integers are within the 1 to 100 range, if not, it should print a message that says "Number is not in range, please try again."

I was given this question for a homework, but i am not expecting any code answer for my question.
I would like some advice and tips on the

'The method/function should also check that the two integers are within the 1 to 100 range, if not, it should print a message that says "Number is not in range, please try again."'

I am pretty much brain dead on how to solve this. Any tips would be awesome!

This is what i am trying but does not work as it

1. does not stop the user from inputing wrong number
2. does not alert the user right away after inputing a wrong value

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Key in integers only in the range between 1 to 100.");

        System.out.println("Please key in your first Integer: ");
        int a = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please key in your second Integer: ");
        int b = scan.nextInt();

        int totaloutput = computeProduct(a, b);
        System.out.println(totaloutput);

    }

    public static int computeProduct(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 < 1 || num1 > 100) {
            System.out.println("invalid range");
        } else if (num2 < 1 || num2 > 100) {
            System.out.println("invalid range");
        }
        int total = num1 * num2;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: the number must be between the min and ma boundary, if (num1 > 0 && num1 < 100), your where close, good job.

Comment: What do you want to be sone when it's invalid?  Do you want to return a certain number, do nothing, or to throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

So you have to validate both the numbers in range.

What you are doing now is first you are checking the `num1` in range if not, then you are checking `num2` is in range, which is wong the first validation should be false for the second validation to be in effect.

So have all the validation in a single if condition.

```java
if(num1 < 1 || num1 > 100 || num2 < 1 || num2 > 100){
    System.out.println("invalid range");
}
```

then you have to terminate the method when you have invalid input.

You can either throw an exception of return defaule value.

Exception:

```java
if(num1 < 1 || num1 > 100 || num2 < 1 || num2 > 100){
    System.out.println("invalid range");
    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Number")
}
```

Default value:

```java
if(num1 < 1 || num1 > 100 || num2 < 1 || num2 > 100){
    System.out.println("invalid range");
    return -1;
}
```

If you go with default value your method should be as below.

```java
public static int computeProduct(int num1, int num2) {
    if(num1 < 1 || num1 > 100 || num2 < 1 || num2 > 100){
        System.out.println("invalid range");
        return -1;
    }
    int total = num1 * num2;
    return total;
}
```